# Access CodeIgniter instance from error pages

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is there any way to access the current instance of CodeIgniter from an error page?  For example, I want to load views from `application/error/error_404.php`, but using `$CI =& get_instance();` to get a reference to the CodeIgniter system doesn't work.  Is this a limitation of working in error pages, and are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to load a view from a place other than Views. The workaround is to customize the error page itself. Have a look at:

- [Custom 404 error pages with CodeIgniter](http://maestric.com/doc/php/codeigniter_404)